# Unable to access the array object that contains @ sign

Tags: php, web

I have an array that contains @sign in the object. I can't access that
Actually I'm parsing XML into array
The `print_r` output is below

```
[link] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                        (
                            [@attributes] => Array
                                (
                                    [type] => text/html
                                    [href] => http://www.livingsocial.com/cities/1964-klang-valley-kuala-lumpur/deals/393950-2-pax-steamboat-set-2-iced-lemon-tea
                                    [rel] => alternate
                                )

                        )
```

$entry->link->**@attributes**->href 
Can't access

Comment: try $entry->link->{'@attributes'}

Comment: that's incorrect syntax ,attributes at xml elements can't have @ sign

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the [attributes()](http://www.php.net/manual/de/simplexmlelement.attributes.php) method to get attributes from a SimpleXMLElement object

```
 $entry->link->attributes();
```

If you want to get the href attribute as string you can do the following:

```
$href = $entry->link->attributes()->href->__toString();
```